# Integrating a python plugin system inside a C++ project

Tags: python, c++, architecture, project

What's the project about: a C++ library on top of which we would like to add a runtime prediction-module which is composed by python plugins (e.g. a plugin for the modeling phase, another one for the prediction, another one for features clustering, etc.). The destination OS is GNU/Linux.

A maybe naive idea is about running a shell script which inside is calling the main python plugin script: so from the main application we would fork into a child process which will be assigned with the shell script file execution. Despite being an easy-to-use solution, it seems to be missing a bit of communication potential.

Do you have any suggestions for a more elegant and robust solution? Or even some reference projects with a similar structure.

Comment: Clairification, you would like to have a C++ _application_ which is running and then a (several) python script(s) which can be used to get data in and out of the C++ application?

Comment: So, the actual C++ application is user-side. It's actually a framework but I've used the term 'library' maybe wrongly because it's the user's duty to link it and exploit its facilities. We're offering plugins to be exploited during an optional stage. These plugins are basically reading/writing tables (which can be CSVs, or even SQL databases tables) in the current implementation and they're managed via shell script calls that makes the actual python scripts execution. Hope It's clearer. And yes, what you said would be the goal but the design phase on this end is still changeable.

Comment: I've also took a quick look at the Python C API, Boost::Python library and similars but I don't know if we're going too much off the road.

Comment: It sounds like you have a lot of existing architecture that is relevant to the problem. You should describe that as much as you can in your post. It sounds like you have some sort of distributed system where users are locally running a cpp application. You are offering web-browser plugins? The computing for these is done on a server? The data tables are on another server?

Comment: Python C API sounds like it might be good